# Bounding the average of a vector valued function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

**Disclaimer:** I edited the question so that it fits Daniel Fischer's comments and it becomes more general. I also provide an answer myself in case anyone might be interested in the solution.

**Question:** Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be continuous and let $A_f=\frac{1}{b-a}\left(\int_a^bf_1(s)\,ds,\ldots,\int_a^bf_n(s)\,ds\right)$ be its average. If $C$ is an open convex subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ such that $f(s)\in C$ for all $s\in[a,b]$ (i.e. the image of $f$ is contained in $C$), how to prove that $A_f\in C$?

Comment: If $C$ is a closed or open convex set, and the values of $f$ lie in $C$, then the average $A_f$ also lies in $C$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Could you provide some hint or reference of the proof?

Comment: [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545398/mean-value-staying-in-a-convex-or-a-subspace)

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

1) First we assume $C$ is an open ball in the $\infty$-norm. We later use this particular case to prove the general result. So if $\|f(s)-v\|_{\infty}<\varepsilon$ for all $s\in[a,b]$, we want to show that $\|A_f-v\|_{\infty}<\varepsilon$.

The $i$-th component of $(b-a)(A_f-v)$ is $$\int_a^bf_i(s)\,ds-(b-a)v_i=\int_a^bf_i(s)\,ds-\int_a^b v_i\,ds=\int_a^bf_i(s)-v_i\,ds.$$ Therefore $$(b-a)\|A_f-v\|_\infty=\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\left|\int_a^bf_i(s)-v_i\,ds\right|\leq\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\int_a^b|f_i(s)-v_i|\,ds.$$ Now, since $\|f(s)-v\|_\infty<\varepsilon$ we have that $|f_i(s)-v_i|<\varepsilon$ for each $i$. We keep bounding to get $$\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\int_a^b|f_i(s)-v_i|\,ds<\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\int_a^b\varepsilon\,ds=(b-a)\varepsilon.$$ It follows that $\|A_f-v\|_\infty<\varepsilon$.

2) Now we prove the general result:

Given $m\geq 1$, let $x_j=a+j\frac{b-a}{m}$ for $j=0,\ldots,m$. For $j=1,\ldots,m$ we denote by $A_f^j$ the average of $f_{|[x_{j-1},x_j]}$, that is $A_f^j=\frac{m}{b-a}\left(\int_{x_{j-1}}^{x_j}f_1(s)\,ds,\ldots,\int_{x_{j-1}}^{x_j}f_n(s)\,ds\right)$. It follows that $A_f$ is the barycentre of $A_f^1,\ldots, A_f^m$: $$A_f=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=1}^mA_f^j.$$ In particular $A_f\in H$, the convex hull of $A_f^1,\ldots,A_f^m$.

Since $C$ is open and the image of $f$ is a compact set contained in it, we can choose $m$ big enough so that for every $j$ the image of $f_{|[x_{j-1},x_j]}$ is contained in an open $\infty$-norm ball $B_j\subseteq C$. According to the lemma we have $A_f^j\in B_j$ and therefore $A_f^j\in C$ for every $j$. Then since $C$ is convex, the convex hull of $A_f^1,\ldots,A_f^m$ is contained in $C$. Therefore we have $A_f\in H\subseteq C$.